# How to reference variables from multiple jobs?

Tags: gitlab-ci

The following renders without errors in the built-in CI lint:

```yaml
.setup:
  variables:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2

my-job:
  variables: !reference [.setup, variables]
  script:
    - echo hello
```

But what if you want to reference variables from multiple jobs?
The following is not validated by the CI lint and will fail:

```yaml
.setup:
  variables:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2

.setup2:
  variables:
    key3: val3
    key4: val4

my-job:
  variables:
    !reference [.setup, variables]
    !reference [.setup2, variables]
  script:
    - echo hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure now that is is not possible to reference the way you want because it make point 'variables entry' to a 'variable entry'. Or a 'variable' to a 'variable'.
Reference looks like a typed pointer. And doing some test, i get some kind of hash inside it.

But may be you could do something like that ?
Declare variables as concatenate string, then explode it later (may be a before script).

```
.setup1:
  variables: 
    array: "key1=val1;key2=val2"

.setup2:
  variables: 
   array: "key3=val3;key4=val4"

my-job:
  stage: build
  variables: 
    setup1vars: !reference [.setup1, variables, array]
    setup2vars: !reference [.setup2, variables, array]

  script:
     - export $(echo $setup1vars | tr \; \\n | while read line ; do echo $line; done  | xargs)
     - export $(echo $setup2vars | tr \; \\n | while read line ; do echo $line; done  | xargs)
     - echo "key1=$key1"
     - echo "key2=$key2"
     - echo "key3=$key3"
     - echo "key4=$key4"
```

I admit this is quite artificial.
Ugly workaround

Answer (score 0):

Did you try extends keyword ?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends
This is a kind of inheritance, you might have multiple inheritance.
Some property will be replaced, but all variables will be taken from all extended jobs. (if multiple variable have the same name, the last one from the last extends will be taken)

```
.setup:
  variables:
    key1: val1
    key2: val2

.setup2:
  variables:
    key3: val3
    key4: val4

my-job:
  extends:
    - .setup
    - .setup2
  script:
    - echo hello
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I used before !reference was available. However I'm looking for a solution for !reference, not using extends.